# DrawText works in Windows, empty in Linux (Synology armv7l)

Tags: skiasharp

I'm having a strange issue where SkiaSharp (2.80.0) *mostly* works in my Synology environment. It can draw shapes and resize and write images. It just never displays text.

The same code renders text just fine when run in Windows.

Here's a code sample just to demonstrate.

```
//In Windows, this produces blue TEST text on top of the resized source image as expected. 
//In the Synology environment, the text is missing, but the image is still successfully resized.

float scale = (float)(RESIZE_WIDTH / originalImage.Width);
using (SKBitmap resizedImage = originalImage.Resize(new SKImageInfo((int)Math.Round(originalImage.Width * scale), (int)Math.Round(originalImage.Height * scale)), SKFilterQuality.High))
{
  using (SKCanvas canvas = new SKCanvas(resizedImage))
  {
    var paint = new SKPaint
      {
        Color = SKColors.Blue,
        IsAntialias = true,
        Style = SKPaintStyle.Fill,
        TextAlign = SKTextAlign.Center,
        TextSize = 90,
        Typeface = SKTypeface.CreateDefault()
      };
      var coord = new SKPoint(resizedImage.Width / 2, (resizedImage.Height + paint.TextSize) / 2);
      canvas.DrawText("TEST", coord, paint);
      canvas.Flush();

      using (var image = SKImage.FromBitmap(resizedImage))
      {
       using (var data = image.Encode())
       {
         using (var stream = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
           data.SaveTo(stream);
       }
     }
  }
}
```

Is there something I need to configure programmatically in SkiaSharp to get DrawText to work in the Synology environment that's just automagic in Windows?

Edit 1: I have now tested this on a Ubuntu install, and DrawText and everything else works fine there.

Edit 2: Add explicit Typeface to sample code

Comment: I'm guessing font loading, try specifying TypeFace

Comment: Thanks for looking at it. I have tried adding this to the SKPaint construction:

`Typeface = SKTypeface.CreateDefault()`

...but no change.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me is to embed font(s) with the app and use SKTypeface.FromStream to load them if the system is unable to provide one.

Thanks to the advice provided by the SkiaSharp community on GitHub:
https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/issues/1564#issuecomment-748581747